# Displaying console.log from other component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

Supposed I have a Home.vue that resides on `components/pages/Home/Home.vue`.

And this is the content which imports the **index.ts**:

```
<template>
   <div>
       Test
   </div>
</template>
<script lang="ts">
import Home from './index'
export default Home
</script>
```

This is the **index.ts** contents:

```
import { Vue } from 'nuxt-property-decorator'

export default class Home extends Vue {
  mounted (): void {
    console.log("awasddddddd");
  }
}
```

And on the `pages/home/index.vue` I imported the **Home.vue** from the components:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <HomePage />
  </div>
</template>
<script lang="ts">
import HomePage from '@/components/pages/Home/Home.vue'
import { Component, Vue } from 'nuxt-property-decorator'

@Component({
  components:
  {
    HomePage
  }
})
export default class Home extends Vue {}
</script>
```

Now I can successfully display the 'Test' however I cant seem to display the **`console.log`** on mounted any idea why is this happening?

Comment: Is there a specific reason you import `index.ts` (and `mounted()`) into your home.vue instead of placing the `mounted()` directly inside your home.vue?

Comment: if you refresh the page you will be able to see the console log, did you check that?